# Linear Programming - Absolute value greater than a constant

Tags: constraints, linear-programming, absolute-value

How would you convert the constraint |x| >= 2 so that it would work in a Linear Program (in particular, solving using Simplex).

I understand how to convert |x| <= 2 as that would become x <= 2 and -x <= 2

However the same logic does not work when you have a minimum constant.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a purely mathematical question, not one about computer programming. ("Linear programming" is a bit of a misleading term; it has no relation with computer programming.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is just no way to shoehorn an equation like `|x|>=2` into a pure (continuous) LP. You need to formulate `x <= -2 OR x >= 2` which is non-convex. This will require a binary variable making the problem a MIP.

One formulation can be:

```
x >= 2 - delta*M
x <= -2 + (1-delta)*M
delta in {0,1}
```

where `M` is judiciously chosen large number. E.g. if `-100<=x<=100` then you can choose `M=102`.

Comment: How can we write a constraint like |x1- a1| +|x2-a2| + .... + |xn - an| >= K ?