# How to write constraint with sum of absolutes in Integer Programming?

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming

I found a solution for just one term [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398506/linear-programming-absolute-value-greater-than-a-constant).

How can we formulate constraints of the form

```
|x1- a1| +|x2-a2| + .... + |xn - an| >= K
```

in Mixed Integer Linear Programming ?

Comment: [Optimization with absolute values](https://optimization.cbe.cornell.edu/index.php?title=Optimization_with_absolute_values).

Comment: This link has examples for objective function but not for constraints with absolute values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write this as:

```
 sum(i, |x[i]-a[i]|) >= K
```

This is non-convex and needs special treatment. Sorry: this is not very simple.

One way to model this is:

```
 x[i] - a[i] = zplus[i] - zmin[i]
 sum(i, zplus[i] + zmin[i]) >= K
 zplus[i] <= δ[i]*M[i]
 zmin[i] <= (1-δ[i])*M[i]
 zmin[i],zplus[i] >= 0
 δ[i] ∈ {0,1}
```

Here M[i] are large enough constants. This needs some thought to find good values. Basically we want: `M[i]=max(|x[i] - a[i]|)`.

Alternative formulations are possible using indicator constraints and SOS1 variables. Some modeling tools and solvers have direct support for absolute values.